# Java 8 Date equal null safe

Tags: java, java-8, date

Which is the best way for checking if two `Date()` object are equals, with null safe feature?
Date d1
Date d2

```
d1 = null, d2 = new Date() => equal false
d1 = null, d2 = null => equal true
d1 = SAME_INSTANT, d2 = SAME_INSTANT => equal true
d1 = new Date(), d2 = YESTERDAY => equal false
```

Comment: `d1 = new Date(), d2 = new Date()` might return `false` for a split second around midnight ;)

Comment: @Thomas since this is the legacy `Date` class, it actually represents a date-time in milliseconds, so the chance of getting two un-equal instances arises once every millisecond. On my machine, the loop `do {} while(new Date().equals(new Date()));` completes in a few milliseconds (between five and forty).

Comment: Why do you still want to use the `Date` class? It’s poorly designed and now long outdated. Use `Instant` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Objects.equals(d1, d2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false otherwise. Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise, equality is determined by using the equals method of the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

Since java-7, use:

```
Objects::equals
```

And stop using `java.util.Date` if you can; use `Instant` when you want `Date` - easier to work with and a lot less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
Optional.ofNullable(d1).map(d -> d.equals(d2)).orElseGet(() -> d2 == null);
```

Works when either is null